# How to search for field values in one table and see if that value is in another table in VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

What I am trying to do is search a Customer table "CUSLST" for CustomerIDs and compare this search to another table to see if there are any hits. If there are no hits, then I would like to add that CustomerID to the other table "tblContact" that I was search for hits in.

```
Private Sub Command3_Click()
Dim rcd As Recordset
Dim rcd_Cust As Recordset
Dim strCriteria As String

Set db = CurrentDb

Set rcd = db.OpenRecordset("tblContact")
Set rcd_Cust = db.OpenRecordset("CUSLST")


rcd_Cust.MoveFirst
With rcd_Cust
    Do Until rcd_Cust.EOF
        strCriteria = rcd![Customer Number]
        If (DoCmd.FindRecord(strCriterial, , True, , True)) = Null Then
            rcd.AddNew
            rcd![Customer Number] = rcd_Cust![Account Code]
            rcd.Update
            rcd_Cust.MoveNext
        End If
        rcd_Cust.MoveNext
    Loop
End With
MsgBox "I'm Done"
End Sub
```

I'm currently getting an error saying: "Compile error: Expected Function or variable"
I'm quite new to VBA so sorry if this is a silly question.

Honestly, I'm not even sure if my logic is correct.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: have you looked at approaching this via SQL, using an update statement with the values derived from a join? `select customer_number from tbl_contact left join CUSTLIST on tbl_Contact.Customer_number=custlist.[account code]`  something like that, not tested.

Comment: I've thought about it, but honestly thought this way would be easier. I'll look into that, thanks

Comment: you can do it in the query designer, open the two tables, and just drag the field you're checking onto the other table you're checking against, and have a play with the criteria, is null for example will show the missing ones.  The correct approach is to use `EXISTS`, that's something for you next... Always think, what will it be like with 1million customers, think how this will work, you're coding what SQL's been coded for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this using a single query:

Create a new query design and open the SQL view then white:

```
INSERT INTO tblContact (Customer Number)
SELECT [Account Code] from CUSLST 
 WHERE [Account Code] NOT IN (SELECT [Customer Number]  from tblContact )
```

Run and enjoy!

Comment: Thank you Ivan! The code runs, but it's giving me the response that 0 rows are appended to tblContact. I just changed it a bit as well.
`INSERT INTO tblContact (CustomerNumber)
SELECT [Account Code] from CUSLST 
 WHERE [Account Code] NOT IN (SELECT [CustomerNumber]  from tblContact );` Do you happen to know what might be wrong?

Comment: First execute `SELECT [Account Code] from CUSLST WHERE [Account Code] NOT IN (SELECT [CustomerNumber] from tblContact );` to preview the rows will be inserted.  and comment what you found.

Comment: @Pokeastuff , changed my query on answer